# SCons, multithreading, management

Tags: python, multithreading, stdout, scons

I'll be short in my question. I'm setting up 'num_jobs' environment option. As you might know it makes SCons run in multithreading mode (depends on cpu count). In my custom builder I call some outer executable via subprocess which prints some output to stdout.

So the question is: how to synchronize that output to stdout? I need to synchronize output because I have 4 cpus and during building I have messed up information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SideEffect`.

```
def MyFunc(env, param):
    run_ret = env.Command(... external command using param ...)

    # ensure that no unit tests are run in parallel
    env.SideEffect('#/GLOABL_LOCK', run_ret)
```

Then `AddMethod` MyFunc to your environment.
The `SideEffect` ensures that the different calls to the `Command` won't be simultaneous.